# C++ development on Windows with CMake + Clang, but Cross Compiling for Linux Arm

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, clang, cross-compiling

I have an existing environment using MSYS and CodeSourcery.2011.09 for ARM as the compiler.  makefiles are the vehicle that builds all the executable images that are run on custom made arm based hardware running Linux as an OS.

I was looking to update the environment to use clang and dreaded having to update a bunch of makefiles.  Then I thought it may be easier to do everything in cmake and it can generate the makefiles for me. I have never used cmake, so it would be a good learning opportunity as well.

So here I am trying to get a demo of this setup and I just can't get cmake to play nice.  I have a "hello world" test file that I can build and run on the target just by running clang++ on the commandline and pipping in all of the arguments needed.

So I know I have what I need, but I can't get cmake to do what I want.  It seems like it just wants to do something with VisualStudio.  I don't have Visual Stuio installed and have no interest in using it at all.   I set the target to build for arm-linux-eabi, but I seem to be unsuccessful.

Anybody have a good tutorial for getting my environment setup to build properly with cmake?  Like I said I can build/run fine using the clang CLI.  It's really wrangling in cmake to do what I want that is stumping me.

It's obvious from the error.log that i'm not building for arm, but I can't get cmake to figure this out.

I've tried many varations of:

```
SET(triple arm-linux-eabi) 
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER C:/LLVM/bin/clang.exe -v)
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_TARGET ${triple}) 
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER C:/LLVM/bin/clang++.exe -v)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_TARGET ${triple})
```

But I just get the following error

```
The output was:
1
clang version 3.9.0 (branches/release_39)
Target: i686-pc-windows-msvc
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: C:\LLVM\bin
 "C:\\LLVM\\bin\\clang.exe" -cc1 -triple i686-pc-windows-msvc18.0.0 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -mincremental-linker-compatible -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name CMakeCCompilerId.c -mrelocation-model static -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -fmath-errno -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -target-cpu pentium4 -v -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=gdb -resource-dir "C:\\LLVM\\bin\\..\\lib\\clang\\3.9.0" -internal-isystem "C:\\LLVM\\bin\\..\\lib\\clang\\3.9.0\\include" -internal-isystem C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/include -internal-isystem C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/include -internal-isystem C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/PlatformSDK/Include -internal-isystem C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 8/VC/include -internal-isystem C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 8/VC/PlatformSDK/Include -fdebug-compilation-dir "C:\\Software\\Vivia\\6.x.x\\ui_test_new_tablet\\pluto\\bluetooth\\CMakeFiles\\3.6.1\\CompilerIdC" -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -fms-extensions -fms-compatibility -fms-compatibility-version=18 -fno-threadsafe-statics -fdelayed-template-parsing -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fdiagnostics-show-option -o "C:\\Users\\BYEE~1.DEK\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\CMakeCCompilerId-c43d47.o" -x c CMakeCCompilerId.c
clang -cc1 version 3.9.0 based upon LLVM 3.9.0 default target i686-pc-windows-msvc
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/PlatformSDK/Include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 8/VC/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 8/VC/PlatformSDK/Include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
  C:\LLVM\bin\..\lib\clang\3.9.0\include
End of search list.
 "link.exe" -out:a.exe -defaultlib:libcmt -nologo "C:\\Users\\BYEE~1.DEK\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\CMakeCCompilerId-c43d47.o"
clang.exe: error: unable to execute command: program not executable
clang.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Thanks for any responses!

Comment: In CMake cross-compiling is performed using [toolchain file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html). Prepare it manually or try to find the one in the net. Configuring CMake for use MSYS generator instead of Visual Studio one is completely unrelated question. As simple approach you may pass `-G MSYS Makefiles` option to `cmake`.

Comment: Thanks, I have gotten further, but I have another issue.  cmake seems to be removing the ' : ' in my windows paths. Is there a way to stop this?   I now get the following error.

clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: '/C/Users/username/Desktop/test/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx'

Comment: Something wrong with your toolchain file: on Windows host CMake shouldn't strip `:` in paths when pass them to executables and shouldn't replace "\" with "/".

Comment: This is basically my toolchain file, see anything obviously wrong? 

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "--sysroot /../../../../Software/Vivia/Limited/ui_dev_ant/Sourcecode/common/arm-sysroot/lts-12.04 -target arm-linux-eabi -mcpu=cortex-a8 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon") 

SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /../../../../LLVM/bin/clang++.exe)

SET(CMAKE_RANLIB /../../../../CodeSourcery-2011.09/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ranlib CACHE INTERNAL STRING)

SET(CMAKE_AR /../../../../CodeSourcery-2011.09/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ar CACHE INTERNAL STRING)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_LINKER "/../../../../LLVM/bin/ld.exe")

Comment: Hm, I am unsure, but MSYS uses Linux-style paths by itself, that is, probably, why CMake generates such paths for it. So, you `clang` installation should understand such paths. Otherwise, you probably need to use generator `MinGW Makefiles` instead: it produces Windows-style paths. As for toolchain file, there is [CMAKE_SYSROOT](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_SYSROOT.html) variable which denotes sysroot (and it is more than compiler flags). Also, for crosscompiling you need to set [CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME.html) variable.